# War deployment on remote Ubuntu tomcat 8.5 not working - but working on local tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I try to deploy my war file on a remote ubuntu tomcat 8.5 server, using the gui manager.
But the deployment faile and give back this error :

[org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]]

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org
/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.faceRecon</groupId>
<artifactId>rest-api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>rest-api</name>
<description>faceRecon rest-api</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>com.faceRecon.restapi.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and here is my java class starting point : Application.java

```
package com.faceRecon.restapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder     application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider to `dockerize` you app - in order to omit this kind of problems in future

Comment: HEy @OleksandrPapchenko ! thanks for your tips, I was considering this at first sight, but i couldn't install docker as I'm running windonws10 basic edition, apparently it require Pro edition.
But i'm probably going to find a way around because it's quite a pain to deploy the way i'm doing it now

Comment: run docker inside ubuntu VM )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the full error message? Did you check the "catalina.log" file?

To me it looks like you could forget to provide MYSQL driver on the remote Tomcat.

Try copying the driver to the Tomcat's "lib" directory and configure it properly like in this example: [Tomcat MYSQL DBCP](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_2_Example)

Comment: Indeed that was the case, thank you very much for your help, it work now